# I need to replace Bearer from the header to verify the Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

```
bearer = bearerHeader.replace("Bearer","");
jwt.verify(bearer, 'super_secret', function (err, decoded) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(decoded);
});
```

Here is my code. Whenever I try to verify Token. I want to replace Bearer from header to verify only token. it will always goes to 'err' if a take Bearer. when i remove the Bearer from header i will work perfect. anyone please help me to solve this. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Output:

```
  { 
     [JsonWebTokenError: invalid token] name: 'JsonWebTokenError',
     message: 'invalid token'
  }

   undefined
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

if bearerHeader is something like "Bearer 456513" then your code

```
bearerHeader.replace("Bearer","");
```

will result: " 456513" (there are space before the token)

```
bearerHeader.replace('Bearer ','');
```

may solve your issue but I recommend to verify the authentification scheme first ("Bearer" term is really "Bearer"):

```
 var parts = bearerHeader.split(' ');
 if (parts.length === 2) {
   var scheme = parts[0];
   var credentials = parts[1];

   if (/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
     token = credentials;
     //verify token
     jwt.verify(token, 'super secret', function(err, decoded) {
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
bearer = bearerHeader.replace(/^Bearer\s/, '');
    jwt.verify(bearer, 'super_secret', function (err, decoded) {
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log(decoded);`
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to `split()` the string on spaces and discard the first element

```js
// OPTION 1
bearerHeader.split(" ")[1];
```

or you can simple cut `Bearer` from the string

```js
// OPTION 2
bearerHeader.replace("Bearer", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

you should have to pass space after Bearer

```
var token = req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution if you need to support multiple authorisation schemes or if you are unsure if bearer will be provided or not.

```js
const authToken = req.headers.authorization
const [token, ...rest] = authToken.split(' ').reverse()
```

With this code, `12345` will be returned for the following test data:

- `12345`
- `Bearer 12345`
- `Basic 12345`